# Prevent clickable image on WooCommerce image

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I try to prevent the clickable image event on WooCommerce by adding the following code. It works fine but after adding it, in the single product page, it shows a text ("open" in this case) above the image. How can I solve this problem?

```
function e12_remove_product_image_link( $html, $post_id ) {
    return preg_replace( "!<(a|/a).*?>!", '', $html );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'e12_remove_product_image_link', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding: `pointer-events: none;` to the class or image tag in css, it will make the container unclickable through CSS.

Regarding the "open" text, it could be coming from a `title` tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) in the image. Which you could try to remove with javascript to remove the text.

I don't know what WooCommerce adds to it's links by default, but one of those defaults might be your issue.

Comment: The problem of  `pointer-events: none;` is that i also have a plugin that gives me the opportunity of zooming on hover. If i add this code it will also prevent the zoom. Btw the "open" is just text, which isn't into a div or anything and it hasn't a class so idk how to remove it.

Comment: Ok i solved the problem, i was just messing with the wrong div, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Cool, great that you've found the issue!